# Installing espeak using pip in Python 3.6

Tags: python, espeak

When I run `pip install espeak`, I get  `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement espeak (from versions: )` . Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: What makes you think it's a `Python` package?

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in a comment, `espeak` is not a Python package available on PyPI.

Perhaps you meant one of these:

```
pip install pyespeak
pip install speake  # Python 2
pip install speake3  # Python 3
```

If none of these packages are the one you need, you can take a look at the list here: https://pypi.org/search/?q=espeak

Comment: Thanks. I was actually trying out an online tutorial that implied it was a Python package. For anyone who has a similar problem in future, I used  `pip install py-espeak-ng`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are after python-espeak, and are running Debian/Ubuntu, you likely want `sudo apt-get install python-espeak`. However, it is quite old and doesn't seem to support `python3`.

I'd recommend simply executing espeak directly using the subprocess module, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

def espeak(text: str, pitch: int=50) -> int:
    """ Use espeak to convert text to speech. """
    return subprocess.run(['espeak', f'-p {pitch}', text]).returncode
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the context of using coqui-ai. For me what worked was to install espeak like this: `brew install espeak`. This discussion helped: https://github.com/coqui-ai/TTS/discussions/1973 .