# I get the following error in console when I try to install python-espeak

Tags: python, python-3.x, espeak

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\carli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\carli\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-pw2vgo81\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\carli\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-pw2vgo81\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\carli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-47y3xo5u\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\carli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\python-espeak'
         cwd: C:\Users\carli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-pw2vgo81\
    Complete output (17 lines):
    running install
    C:\Users\carli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\espeak
    copying espeak\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\espeak
    running build_ext
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\espeak
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\carli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\carli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpespeak/espeakmodulecore.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\espeak/espeakmodulecore.obj
    espeakmodulecore.cpp
    espeak/espeakmodulecore.cpp(23): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'espeak/speak_lib.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\carli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\carli\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-pw2vgo81\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\carli\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-pw2vgo81\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\carli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-47y3xo5u\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\carli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\python-espeak' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607994/installing-espeak-using-pip-in-python-3-6

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have [espeak](https://github.com/espeak-ng/espeak-ng/) installed? The python package you're trying to install is a wrapper, meaning it allows you to use the espeak functionality from within python.

Once you have espeak installed, make sure it's included in your PATH environment variable.

If `python-espeak` installation still doesn't work, there are more espeak wrappers available that may have been better maintained. Look here: https://github.com/espeak-ng/espeak-ng/

Answer (score 0):

`python-espeak` is a just a wrapper for it to work in python, so you need to have `espeak` installed and in your PATH variable for this to work.

https://github.com/espeak-ng/espeak-ng/blob/master/docs/guide.md

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31304638)